# opkg can't find apache

Tags: software-installation, package-management, apache-httpd, angstrom, opkg

I'm trying to get a LAMP stack running on my BeagleBone Black, but I'm getting foiled early: opkg can't seem to find the apache2 package.

According to the Angstrom page, it should exist:
http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/ (search "apache" for confirmation)

...but when I run opkg, it can't find it.

This is what I see:

```
root@beaglebone:~# opkg install apache2
Unknown package 'apache2'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package apache2.
root@beaglebone:~# opkg list | grep apache2
php-fpm-apache2 - 5.3.19-r4.0.1 - php version 5.3.19-r4.0
```

...and naturally, that's after running opkg update.

Answer (score 1):

This thread might shed some light on your issue. The thread is titled: [BeagleBone and missing packages... I'm confused](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/beagleboard/0Nl97LMkRFE).

In the thread they discuss that they aren't able to install some kernel modules and python. Seems to be some confusion in determining which version of BeagleBone you have installed and which versions of the packages in the repository you can/can't install.

This second thread, titled: [sudo package missing from recent angstrom?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/bsiWha74mc8) , shows a method for downloading the packages and installing them manually. There is some additional discussion in this thread around the fact that some of the packages are tagged in the repository for specific versions and architectures.

So if `opkg` isn't cooperating for you, you could just manually download the `.ipkg` files needed for [apache2](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/?pkgname=apache2) and install them manually.

Comment: Thanks. I'd done no shortage of googling and reading and googling some more, but I hadn't turned up these and likely wouldn't have.

Comment: Are there .ipkg files available for your hardware? I wasn't entirely sure what you actually had. I see the black edition of BB, is that what you have?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The B3 (BeagleBone Black) has an ARM Cortex-A8 proc, and the closest the ipkg goes is A7a. So right there at first glance, there's an issue. But just having been helped over that last hurdle and knowing where to look next is reinvigorating. This is my first time mucking with opkg, and I'm wondering now how tricky it'd be to create the A8 port for it. Or if I could get to work faster on building what I want atop LAMP if I just jumped ship for B3's Ubuntu distro. I'll take a peek at writing a new ipkg first. If I can help the next guy along by providing that, I'd like that.

Comment: You'll need the development tools, there is probably a way to cross compile for A8 on some other platform...maybe. That's typically how it's done though.

Comment: Thanks again. I figured I'd start by compiling it for OSX, my daily platform and a well-mapped process, to know what it was supposed to look like. With that behind me, I'd do a cross platform compile for A8.